# Compare Two Columns In A Data Frame And If False Then Capture Value of Another Column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set in which I want to compare two columns. For each row where these column don't match I want to capture the corresponding row value of another value and write it in another data frame.

**Input Data**

```
data <- structure(list(A = 1:7, B = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L), C = c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

**Expected Output**

```
  A
1 2
2 3
3 5
4 6
5 7
```

Currently I am using following code but this leads to empty rows when the value for `B` and `C` column matches in **Input Data**. I want to keep those of `A` for which `B` and `C` don't match.

Is it possible to it any another way so ensure above condition is met?

**Code**

```
ifelse(data$B == data$C, 
      data$A, "")
```

**Output of Above Code**

```
[1] ""  "2" "3" ""  "5" "6" "7"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `subset`

```
subset(data, B != C, select = A)
#  A
#2 2
#3 3
#5 5
#6 6
#7 7
```

---

Or with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    filter(B != C) %>%
    select(A)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[B != C, .(A)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select `A` values where `B != C` and then add it to a new data frame.

```
data.frame(A = data$A[data$B != data$C])

#  A
#1 2
#2 3
#3 5
#4 6
#5 7
```

If you just need vector of values you could do

```
data$A[data$B != data$C]
#[1] 2 3 5 6 7
```

---

In `ifelse` we are replacing the values which do not satisfy the condition with empty space (`""`) hence the length of output is same as number of rows in `data`.